# Code coverage is not showing on Sonarqube for Typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, sonarqube, nestjs

I am using Sonarqube analysis for my Nestjs project. While I run the unit tests with jest, they are all passing and code coverage was about 80%. On Sonarqube it is still showing as 0%.

My **sonar-project.properties** file is as follows

```
sonar.projectKey=<project-key>
sonar.projectName=
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=src
sonar.inclusions=**
sonar.test.inclusions=src/**/*.spec.ts
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=test-report.xml
sonar.exclusions=node_modules
```

My jest.json is as follows

```
{
"moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "json"
  ],
  "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "/src/.*\\.(test|spec).(ts|tsx|js)$",
  "collectCoverageFrom" : ["src/**/*.{js,jsx,tsx,ts}", "!**/node_modules/**", "!**/vendor/**"],
  "coverageReporters": ["json", "lcov"]
}
```

The relevant parts of my package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
"@nestjs/cli": "^7.5.4",
"@nestjs/schematics": "^7.2.7",
"@nestjs/testing": "^7.6.11",
"@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
"@types/node": "^14.14.25",
"@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.2",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.2",
"eslint": "^7.19.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"jest-sonar-reporter": "^2.0.0",
"prettier": "^2.2.1",
"serverless": "^2.23.0",
"supertest": "^6.1.3",
"ts-jest": "^26.5.0",
"ts-loader": "^8.0.15",
"ts-node": "^9.1.1",
"tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
"typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "jest": {
"testResultsProcessor": "jest-sonar-reporter",
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "js",
  "json",
  "ts"
],
"rootDir": "src",
"testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
},
"collectCoverageFrom": [
  "**/*.(t|j)s"
],
"coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
"testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

My source code and their respective unit tests are in the same location. The test files have the extension .spec.ts

While running tests locally, all tests are passing and test-report.xml is generated on the local repo.  We are also running unit tests on Jenkins as a stage just before running sonar scanner.

Sonarqube code coverage is important metric for us and without which the pipeline does not move further. Any tips here?

Sonarqube Enterprise Edition Version 7.9.5 (build 38598)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried specifying the path to your **lcov.info** file like so:
`sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info`

These parameters are documented [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.9/analysis/coverage/):

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain, but your symptoms match what I saw when I discovered a bug in the SonarTS plugin.  We're using a somewhat old version of SonarQube (7.9.2).  You haven't said what version you're using.

What I discovered from somewhat random experimentation is that if a file path in the "lcov.info" file crosses a symbolic link, the SonarTS plugin will not be able to open the file, thus finding zero coverage for that file.  If a single file in the lcov.info file crosses a symbolic link, it's likely that all of them will.

I fixed this by writing a script that processes the lcov.info file, replacing all file paths with their "absolute" file paths, following symbolic links.

The code in our Jenkins shared library looks something like this:

```
shterse "cat coverage/lcov.info | " +
   "while IFS= read -r line; do if [[ \"\$line\" == \"SF:\"* ]]; then line=\"SF:\$(realpath \"\${line#SF:}\")\"; fi; echo \"\$line\"; done > /tmp/lcov.info"
sh "mv /tmp/lcov.info coverage/lcov.info"
```

Where "shterse" is this:

```
// This will turn off verbose output.
def shterse(cmd) {
    sh('#!/bin/sh -e\n' + cmd)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately, this is not an option for me in our pipeline. We do not control the Jenkins Master and only certain groovy scripts are approved. I updated the question with the version now.

Answer (score 0):

Update add below line to jest config.

```
"coverageReporters": [
      "html",
      "lcov"
    ]
```

Update sonar file to have below line(if you dont have one create new in root with this name `sonar-project.properties`)

```
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```